# Apache & Node Reverse proxy, Socket Timeout, Keepalive

Tags: node.js, apache, timeout, reverse-proxy, keep-alive

I have an API application built with node and expressjs. Using Apache for reverse proxy, with keepalive enabled.

Some requests (specifically POST/PUT), will end up hanging for 2 minutes due to the default 2 minute socket timeout. Doesn't happen always, but often. As soon as the timeout is hit, the Client then gets the response and continues sending other requests.

It seems to be due to Keep-Alive, although I'm not 100% sure.

Adding the header:

```
res.set('Connection', 'close');
```

Makes the problem go away, that's why I think this is related to keep-alive.

Been researching the issue for 2 days with no success.

Is it worth setting the header and accepting the consequences, or is there any other solution/explanation to this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was all caused by a "204 - No Content" response on DELETE requests sent **before** the PUT/POST requests. Changing from

```
res.send(data)
```

To

```
res.status(204).end()
```

Fixed the issue for me.